# SSHFS: Permission denied when opening directory from application even with "allow_other"

Tags: linux, linux-mint, sshfs, fuse, snap

I'm trying to use sshfs to open a remote directory in the Spotify snap application on Linux Mint.

```
sshfs -o allow_other user@example.com:/remote/dir /local/dir
```

I've mounted my directory using the "allow_other" fuse option, and the directory opens without having to use sudo in terminal and file explorer. However, when I try adding it as a directory in Spotify for local files, the file explorer gives me this message:

[image: Spotify error]

Any advice on fixing this? I've tried modifying the permissions of the folder and "default_permissions" option, no luck yet.

Comment: According to sshfs(1), the option is actually named `--allow_others` (trailing 's'), and it should be used with `-o default_permissions`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: Which users are running `sshfs` and Spotify (and the file picker you're showing)? Is AppArmor enabled on your system? Also, to make `allow_other` be effective when used by non-root users, `user_allow_other` has to be uncommented in `/etc/fuse.conf` (see the manual for fuse(8)).

Comment: I assume it's all running on the same user, since I'm opening Spotify and running sshfs on the same computer (and user). Though the Spotify app is a snap application and I'm not running that from terminal, so could that make a difference? Also, I did already uncomment `user_allow_other` Also how do I check if AppArmor is enabled on Linux Mint?

Comment: I ran `aa-status` and saw that a few profiles with `snapd` in the directory name are in enforce mode. Could that be why? EDIT: One of them is `snap.spotify.spotify`,

Answer (score 0):

Seems like snap applications don't allow me to disable the AppArmor protection easily. Thankfully, Spotify for Linux had a 2nd version as a Debian package which didn't have the same issue. Not technically solved but solved enough for me!